# create objects of type vector<type> for structure variables

Tags: c++, vector

I got a structure with two variables, char first_name and last_name. How can I declare first_name and last_name as objects of type `vector<char>`

```
 struct employee{
    char first_name[50];
    char last_name[50];
  }
```

when I used std::vector first_name[50], it is throwing an error: expected a type specifier. How should I resolve it

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Why not use `std::string` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have a list of employees as a vector:

```
struct employee{
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_names;
};

std::vector<employee> myvec;
employee e1;
e1.first_name = "tom";
e1.last_name = "joe";
myvec.push_back(e1);

std::cout << myvec[0].first_name << std::endl; // tom
std::cout << myvec[0].last_name << std::endl; // joe
```

Now if you want a list of first names and last names as strings,in an EMPLOYEES struct, then:

```
    struct employees{
      std::vector<std::string> first_names;
      std::vector<std::string> last_name;
    };

    std::string firstname = "tom";
    std::string lastname = "joe";

    employees e;
    e.first_names.push_back(firstname);
    e.last_names.push_back(lastname);

    std::cout << e.first_names[0] << std::endl; // tom
    std::cout << e.last_names[0] << std::endl;  // joe
```

I think having a struct of employee and creating a list of them, makes more sense, but I do not know how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you wrote it:

```
struct employee{
    std::vector<char> first_name;
    std::vector<char> last_name;
};
```